# CSS animation-delay not working as expected

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to implement this simple animation for a rock-paper-scissors game I'm developing:

http://jsfiddle.net/franciov/kbngz27s/1/

```
@keyframes arm-out {
    from {
        left: 0em;
    }
    to {
        left: 5em;
    }
}

.player > .arm.out {
    animation-name: arm-out;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Basically, I want the player to:

1. pull back his arm when the game loads (arm-in animation)
2. show his arm when the 'Play' button is clicked (arm-out animation) Note: I would like the player to show the arm after a while, at the moment this is implemented with a window.setTimeout but I would like to use the animation-delay property
3. show the hand shape after a delay (reveal animation, in JSFiddle the shape is always 'scissors')

The animation-delay for the point (3) works well:

```
@keyframes reveal {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.hand.reveal {
    animation-name: reveal;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

but when I try to add a animation-delay property for the point (2), things does not work properly anymore, as you can try on the next JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/franciov/kbngz27s/2/

```
.player > .arm.out {
    animation-name: arm-out;
    animation-delay: 0.8s; /* This is not working properly */
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Any ideas?

I tried the JSFiddles above on Chrome 45.0.2454.101 and Firefox 43.0a2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to add `left: 0;` to `.arm.out`, because at the moment you click the button, **it removes the `in` class and you have `left: 5em;` in your `arm` class.**

Set the left position of "out arm" to zero then let the animation do the job.

```
.player > .arm.out {
    left: 0; /* Add this one. */
    animation-name: arm-out;
    animation-delay: 0.8s; /* This is working for me (Chrome 45) */
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/kbngz27s/3/
(Added some time to `.hand.reveal` so it doesn't appear before the arm). Strangely *it sometimes fails as you say*, but not every time...